# Unable to generate Facebook Like button

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-like

I am trying to create a "like button" for www.songmeanings.net

It works for several other addresses except for www.songmeanings.net.  Is there any particular reason why this could be?

Try it here

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Type in google.com, hit enter.  Works perfectly
Type in songmeanings.net hit enter.  Nothing

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's because of the unterminated `<noscript>` tag on line 36. Or perhaps [something similar](http://htmlhelp.com/cgi-bin/validate.cgi?url=http://www.songmeanings.net/&warnings=no).

Comment: Are you sure about that?  It's not even working on the Facebook Like Plugin Generator

Comment: No, I'm not sure. I suspect it's not working because of an html error. Did you click the 'something similar' link above?